# jQuery navigation plugin refreshes the entire page. How do I fix this

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, carousel

I have a [site](http://www.creativestyle.com/) where I use a jquery slider plugin. For the previous/next slide navigation, I applied absolute positioning. Now the navigation is working but it refreshes the whole page again. Can anyone give me the solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question with more information including the relevant code?  Which plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your HTML and noticed that the navigation links look like this:

```
<a href class="prev">
```

Because the link doesn't have any href the browser treats it as "redirect to same/home page".
I don't know if this is what you have to fix in your markup or in the plugin but if you change it to the following format the problem will be solved:

```
<a href="#" class="prev">
```